# NAS as normal storage drive?

Tags: nas

Is it possible to use an NAS system as a regular non-network storage? IE: plugging a cable from it to a computer, and then being able to use all the drives as if they where an external one, without the latency of using wireless connection.

Comment: Why not use a wired network connection?  Most of our servers at work use network-attached storage over 1GB or 10GB Ethernet, works pretty well.

Comment: Why does the latency matter to you? What do you intend to do that is latency dependent? Or is it just for info?

Answer (score 0):

No. That is not the role of a NAS equipment. What you are describing it's called Direct-attached storage or DAS.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-attached_storage